# Testing Facebook Terms of Service Violation Error?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am writing error handling around a case where users have recently violated terms of service with Facebook, and need a way to test this out. I've been reading through their docs and can't seem to find any tools for doing this. Any advice from someone with experience testing this would be greatly appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much you have to either get an account temporarily banned or somehow contact Facebook developer support.